# How to convert a int array into a long array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to convert my ordered int array into a long array,
this is what my my conversion currently looks like:

```
long[] arraylong = new long[array.Length];
```

my issues arise when I want to apply this calculation:

```
longmid = lowlong + ((searchValueLong - arraylong[lowlong]) * (highlong - lowlong)) 
    / (arraylong[highlong] - arraylong[lowlong]);
```

and I get an exception of type `DivideByZeroException`.
The values that are zero after the conversion are `arraylong[lowlong]` and `arraylong[highlong]`

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to give.

Comment: That's not a conversion, you're just creating an array of the same length with all zeros in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To convert the `int[]` use linqs `Select` and in it explicitly cast to `long`:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var longs = ints.Select(item => (long)item).ToArray();
```

In your code above you've only initialized a `long[]` to the size of the `int[]` and the items get the default value - which for `long` is zero - causing your `DivideByZeroException`

---

Note that using `ints.Cast<long>().ToArray();` will not work and throw an `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a conversion, you're just creating an array of the same length with all default values (i.e. all zero.) There's various ways to convert your array, one is to use the Linq `Select` method:

```
long[] arrayLong = array.Select(i => (long)i).ToArray();
```